# Manipulate every row in a dataframe as a new dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

I would like to manipulate every row in df1:

```
print(df1)

| ID | Col1 | Col2 | ... | Col5 |
---------------------------------
| 123|  A   |  B   | ... |  E   |
| 456|  A1  |  B1  | ... |  E1  |
```

and output to a new dataframe exactly like below:

```
| ID | Col_Num | Ans |
----------------------
| 123|  Col1  |  A  |
| 123|  Col2  |  B  |
| 123|  Col3  |  C  |
| 123|  Col4  |  D  |
| 123|  Col5  |  E  |
| 456|  Col1  |  A1 |
| 456|  Col2  |  B1 |
| 456|  Col3  |  C1 |
| 456|  Col4  |  D1 |
| 456|  Col5  |  E1 |
```

I have created a function that does this if I give it a single row.

My question is how can I apply that function to every row. I believe a for loop will be inefficient if I have a large dataset of 1000 rows.

I have tried:

```
df1.apply(function, axis= 1) 
df1.apply(lambda x: function, axis= 1)
```

Comment: `df.melt(id_vars='ID')`

Comment: `df.melt(id_vars='ID').sort_values('ID')`